# Set sum random sample

Tags: r, random, sample

So this seems like a really simple question to me, but I can't seem to figure it out. I'm using R and I'm trying to generate a random sample, where the generated sample all sums to a set number.

Comment: You do know about the Central Limit Theorem, right?

Answer (score 1):

Here's an approach to consider.  Generate some random numbers:

```
n   = 10
x <- runif(n) # or rnorm, rpois, whatever you want to use
```

And then `scale()` them to get the sum you want.

```
tot = 100 # this is the sum you want
x <- scale(x, center=FALSE, scale=sum(x)/tot)
all.equal(sum(x), tot) #TRUE
```